# Octopress/Ruby Having this error: Pygments can't parse unknown language when trying to create a code block

Tags: ruby, octopress

I just started to use octopress today, and when I tried to add a code block to my blog post, I have this error:

```
Error:  Pygments can't parse unknown language: swift
```

My post was written like this:

````
---
layout: post
title: "test"
date: 2016-01-23 13:46:07 -0600
comments: true
categories: trial
---
<code>asdasd</code>
``` swift Trial

let haha = "String"
```
````

After doing some research, I am almost certain it is because my environment is using python3 now, and ruby does not support python3.

It is confirmed by running this command line

```
$ env python
```

From the internet, I saw people having solve this problem by modifying

```
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pygments.rb-0.3.4/lib/pygments/mentos.py
```

But that was for ruby 1.9.3. My problem is I am using ruby 2.0 now, and I cannot find the python file to modify. So what I should do in this case?

Thanks in advance!!! Have been stuck on this for a whole afternoon.

Comment: The problem is that your version of Pygments (the syntax highlighter used by Octopress) doesn't know how to highlight Swift code. https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/1715

Comment: @Jordan, thanks for the quick reply. Sorry I did not include my test. I have tried other languages, but pygments cannot read ruby, python, javascript, etc either. So I guess it is not the version problem?

Comment: Here is the website that seems to be the solution when using ruby 1.9.3: http://binarystud.io/blog/2014/05/23/octopress-deployment-and-issues/

Comment: I don't think the ruby version really matters that much. Do you use `rbenv` to manage ruby versions?

Comment: @cozyconemotel, yes, I used rbenv. Is this the culprit?

Comment: well, then, if you installed the gem globally, it should be in `~/.rbenv/versions/[your ruby version]/lib/ruby/gems/[your ruby version]/gems/pygments.rb-[version]/lib/pygments/mentos.py`.. but if you installed it locally, say in `vendor/bundle` in your octopress directory, then it should be in `vendor/bundle/ruby/[your ruby version]/gems/pygments.rb[version]/lib/pygments/mentos.py`

Comment: @cozyconemotel. Yes! I did install the gem locally. But what is weird is that I still do not have the directories as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested and verified that Octopresss support swift code highlight.

Here are some screenshot to show you what i did.

Try to download and to use the latest version.
Im working with Octopress v3.

[image]
[image]